# .NET WebAPI DataModel - "one element or another" required data annotation

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, model-validation

My web service is required to accept a model that contains a number of elements.  The domain is broadcast media.

One of the requirements of the model is that it contains EITHER a `<digital></digital>` element or a `<physical></physical>` element.

So either this is acceptable:

```
<media>
  <digital>video/x-mxf</digital>
</media>
```

OR:

```
<media>
  <physical>Betacam</physical>
</media>
```

My class is looking like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Media
{
   [DataMember]
   public string physical { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string digital { get; set; }
}
```

In WebAPI, I can obviously apply the RequiredAttribute to a property, but that's not what I want in this case, because I want EITHER one element OR the other.

Is there anyway to do the model validation using attributes, in this case?

Comment: You may need to use custom validation attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx. You may apply it at class level and in the IsValid() method you get the ValidationContext to investigate the object being validated.

Comment: I thought about this, but how would such an attribute be constructed? With a "reference" in its constructor, that gets added to a static dictionary? It's the creation of this attribute I'm struggling with, because applying it to two separate properties would create two separate attribute objects when instantiated. Ideally I'd want the same attribute instantiation applied to both properties, if that makes sense?

Comment: You should be able to add the Attribute to the whole class. the `IsValid` method accepts a `ValidationContext` parameter which has a `ObjectInstance` representing the object being validated (your class). You can cast this to `Media` and then read all the property values you want. What have you tried already?

Comment: Well, not what you described. I was thinking of a more generic attribute that you applied to the individual properties.  Like an "ExclusivelySetAttribute".

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I was probably confusing ideas in the comment... You should do something along these lines:

First add the CustomValidation attribute to your class:

```
[DataContract]
[CustomValidation(typeof(MediaValidation), "Validate")] 
public class Media
{
    [DataMember]
    public string physical { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string digital { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a `MediaValidation` class (same class name you specified in the attribute), with a `public` and `static` method called `Validate` (as specified in the attribute again), that returns a `ValidationResult`... The first argument of this method is exactly your object being validated. You can do something like:

```
public class MediaValidation
{
    public static ValidationResult Validate(Media model, ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.physical) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.digital))
            return new ValidationResult("Either physical or digital must be specified");
        else
            return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

**UPDATE: alternative solution**

Another way would be to extend the `ValidationAttribute` as you were doing, and apply your extended attribute at class level (rather than the individual properties). You will need to override the `IsValid()` method:

```
public class ExclusivelySetAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var model = value as Media;
        if (model == null)
            return false; // or your logic, throw an exception...

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.physical) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.digital))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

When you return false, the error message shown will be the one specified in the attribute:

```
[ExclusivelySet(ErrorMessage = "Either physical or digital must be specified")]
public class Media
{
    //... your code
}
```

Let me know how this approach works for you.

Comment: Seems a perfectly valid answer! For some reason I wasn't aware of the CustomValidationAttribute.  I have been deriving my own for a while, where using CustomValidationAttribute would have been simpler.

Comment: Just as an FYI for anyone reading this, ValidationAttributes applied to the model itself appear to have some issues.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113608/net-web-api-framework-throws-argumentnullexception-if-validationattribute-is-a

Comment: Whilst this works in certain scenarios, it causes problems in others, so I'm still looking for a better solution to this issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an alternative approach extending the `ValidationAttribute`. It seems a bit more streamlined as a solution. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hi Tallmaris, this didn't work for me either, for the reasons explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113608/net-web-api-class-level-validation-attribute-causes-web-api-to-throw-argumentn .  I did find an another solution though, which I'll post shortly.

Comment: Interesting... probably the framework, when there is a custom attribute, is trying to create a `ValidationContext` to pass to the custom validator and fails because the object is null. If there are no custom validators then it does not even try to create the context and everything goes ok... Since you are using the WebApi, why don't you just check that the object is valid when you get it in the POST and PUT methods?

Comment: I think you're exactly right: Reflector suggested that it was trying create a ValidationContext when the exception was thrown.  The execution wasn't even reaching my POST and PUT methods when the exception was returned to the user, but that's possibly because I have a filter that performs the validation before it reaches the controller.  I'll have a check.

Comment: CustomValidationAttribute rules. I've missed it somehow as well, but not anymore :-)